# Unable to switch back to the parent window from the popup frame using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have the login page, when click login its opens the new tab. I moved the control to new tab using

```
driver.switchTo().window("");
// Done some stuffs in new window.
```

when I click one Button it will open the popup (frame).

I have selected a popup window using `driver.switchTo().frame("frameName");`

and from there by selecting the record, the popup window will be closed. The selected record will be displayed in parent window and the page got refreshed.

Now I want to return(Re-Focus) the control to my parent window for doing the some other stuffs.

but I could not focus the parent window again.

I have tried:

```
driver.switchTo().defaultcontent();
driver.switchTo().window("");
```

and

```
driver.getWindowHandles();
```

Still the same result....

Could anyone please help me on this....

Answer (score 2):

```
String oldWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='searchSalesImg']/img")).click(); 
//by clicking on this we will get a new window

Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandle());

driver.switchTo().window("Employer Services Order Management (ESOM)"); 
//Navigate to new window
driver.findElement(By.id(" Primary Sales Person:")).sendKeys("MAS%"); 
//Do some stuff in new window

driver.switchTo().window(oldWindow); 
//navigate back to old window
```

Comment: @GaborSch:
Thanks for your reply. But i m not switching back from the window to Window. i m switching back from the frame to Window.
i tried with this but could not get any result.... 
facing the same pbm....

Comment: The answer came from @ginne I just reviewed it.

Comment: @GaborSch : Ok , thanks for that. if u have any idea please share it. i m facing this pbm.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code:-

driver.switchTo().frame("Frame_identifier");

//your code

String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
  webDriver.SwitchTo().Window(winHandleBefore);